# Linux Mint is installing programs to / and not /home, how do I resolve this?

Tags: package-management, root, home, root-filesystem

I have an issue with Linux Mint saving things to root and not the home directory. I need assistance with this, a friend is being rather persistent about it. Every time a package is installed it defaults to the root directory instead of being installed to the home directory.

Comment: If you're installing packages from Mint, that's perfectly normal. Could you [edit] your question to clarify how you're installing packages, and why your friend thinks they should go to `/home`?

Comment: He has 6GB of root and 277GB in /home because it was originally supposed to be for all the things he would install.

Comment: I set up the drive in the same manner I set up all of my Linux Systems. Root, home, and swap.

Comment: @nerd7473: Only 6GB of root? Well, these open-source operating systems give you so much freedom that it's easy to make rookie mistakes. It's a learning experience, isn't it? If reinstalling is not an option, you *could* read the mount(8) man page to learn to set up a bind mount, but I believe that you would find this frustrating; hard to make it do what you really want in your case. If possible, it would probably be best to repartition and reinstall. Good luck.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to delete the /home and expand root. Or I'll help him to shrink /home and then expand /.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Debian-derived system like Mint, DEB packages are not meant to be installed in a user's home directory. They are to be installed by the system administrator for systemwide use.

Even if a package could be installed in a user's home directory, the package would not work after being installed there.  Rather, a package is to be installed systemwide.

When installed systemwide, a typical package `foo` might place

- an executable program at `/usr/bin/foo`,
- a set of configuration files in `/etc/foo/`,
- auxiliary files needed by the executable program in `/usr/lib/foo/` and/or `/usr/share/foo/`,
- documentation in `/usr/share/doc/foo/`,

and so on. Then, if the program maintains persistent or runtime data, that goes in `/var/` and/or `/run/`. It's pretty complicated. That is why the software is packaged, so that your friend does not have to deal with all that complexity.

Now, some *unpackaged* software can, with sufficient effort, be installed in a user's home directory (if not in `/usr/local/`); but for most users, most of the time, that would be a special case.